# SQL query for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables students, class and grades. I need to make a query that will count how many specific grades are for specific class. And also calculate average grade for specific class where grade 1 is not included (grades are 1,2,3,4,5).

Columns for the query should look like this:

```
Class  | Grade 1 |   Grade 2  |   Grade 3  |   Grade 4  |  Grade 5  |   Average (except 1)
```

I know how to get result for one specific grade:

```
select C.ClassName, count(G.Grade)
from Classes C, Grades G
where G.ClassesID = C.ClassesID and G.Grade = 1
group by C.ClassName
```

but how do I make a query to get all columns at once?

Comment: this screams homework! And the use of implied syntax is a SQL antipattern, do not learn to use it, learn to correctly use explicit joins.

Comment: Yeah, first post, very homework like question.  Next.

Comment: It's not really a homework. And sorry if it's a stupid question I didn't do anything in sql for long time. I would apreciate if someone can help me with this one

Comment: I told you where to look for your answer. Try to make CASE work and comeback if you can't figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean "not really homework?" If it's a an assignment from an educational institution for a grade, it's homework. All we're asking you to do is to tag it as such if it is.

Comment: It is not assignment from educational institution and I will not get a grade for it

Comment: Turning values into columns in the result is known as "pivoting".  I've suggested an edit to your question's title to reflect this.

Comment: @Simon -- your suggested edit was rejected only because PIVOT is just one possible answer for this.  I up-voted your answer that shows how to use Pivot though.

Comment: PIVOT (the T-SQL keyword) is only one way to pivot a result set.  My statement that creating a result like this is called "pivoting" is valid no matter what technique you use to do it.  Either way, people searching for a similar answer would be well served by a more specific title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try SUBQUERY. If you use MSSQL you can try this:

```
SELECT C.ClassName, 
--Grade 1
(SELECT COUNT(G1.Grade) 
FROM Classes C1, Grades G1 
WHERE G1.ClassesID = C1.ClassesID and G1.Grade = 1 and C1.ClassName = C.ClassName),
--Grade 2
(SELECT COUNT(G2.Grade) 
FROM Classes C2, Grades G2 
WHERE G2.ClassesID = C2.ClassesID and G2.Grade = 2 and C2.ClassName = C.ClassName),    
-- Grade 3
(SELECT COUNT(G3.Grade) 
FROM Classes C3, Grades G3 
WHERE G3.ClassesID = C3.ClassesID and G3.Grade = 3 and C3.ClassName = C.ClassName),
--Grade 4
(SELECT COUNT(G4.Grade) 
FROM Classes C4, Grades G4 
WHERE G4.ClassesID = C4.ClassesID and G4.Grade = 4 and C4.ClassName = C.ClassName),
--Grade 5
(SELECT COUNT(G5.Grade) 
FROM Classes C5, Grades G5 
WHERE G5.ClassesID = C5.ClassesID and G5.Grade = 5 and C5.ClassName = C.ClassName)
-- Average (except 1)
(SELECT SUM(GA.Grade) / COUNT(GA.Grade) 
FROM Classes CA, Grades GA 
WHERE GA.ClassesID = CA.ClassesID and GA.Grade NOT IN (1) and CA.ClassName = C.ClassName)

FROM Classes C, Grades G
WHERE G.ClassesID = C.ClassesID
GROUP BY C.ClassName
```

Aliases for the tables are not necessary. -- Means comment.

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL Server is new enough (2005 or newer), `PIVOT` can save you a lot of trouble here.

```
SELECT ClassName, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], ([1] + [2] + [3] + [4] + [5])/5 as [Average Count]
FROM
(
    select C.ClassName, G.Grade
    from Classes C
    join Grades G on G.ClassesID = C.ClassesID
) AS source
PIVOT
(
    count(G.Grade)
    FOR Grade IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
) as pvt
```

Comment: I get some kind of errors. I never used PIVOT before so I'm not really sure how it works but I will check it out and try to figure out why is not working

Comment: @Sima -- FWIW -- PIVOT would be a much better solution for you than Tom's answer that you accepted.  I know it's a bit wierd-looking at first, but you won't regret learning how to do this approach.